# making the result of summary() to be vertically

Tags: r, dataframe, break, cut

the code is attached below and I am writing to ask if there is way to make the result of summary(Eucs.cut) to appear to be vertical instead of showing horizontally.

```
install.packages('GLMsData')
library('GLMsData')
data(nminer)
breaks<-c(-Inf,4,11,15,19,Inf)+0.5
Eucs.cut<-cut(nminer$Eucs,breaks)
summary(Eucs.cut)
```

I tried to use `t(summary(Eucs.cut)`, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that if I use

`cbind(summary(Eucs.cut))` it works.

Very welcome to more ideas.